# java.io.EOFException not a SequenceFile on empty file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, sequencefile

I'm trying to read a table using spark.

```
spark.table("table_name")
sc.sequenceFile(path, classOf[Text], classOf[Text], 1000).
  map(x => x._2.toString.split(delimiter, -1))
```

Both work if there are no empty files and both fail with `java.io.EOFException: /path/to/file/1612735495084_12eed62a-b1ee-4cf5-8b71-a87149acd9c8.sf not a SequenceFile` if the table contains empty files.

Setting `spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true` did not help. Seems like 0 byte file is not considered corrupted.

I can't modify the source table, only my own code. Is there a way to ignore empty files when reading this table?

Using spark 2.2, scala 2.11

```
     diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.SaveAsHiveFile$class.saveAsHiveFile(SaveAsHiveFile.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.saveAsHiveFile(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.processInsert(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.run(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:308)
    at ru.gjin.gjin.system.Main$.delayedEndpoint$ru$gjin$gjin$system$Main$1(Main.scala:30)
    at ru.gjin.gjin.system.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:12)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at ru.gjin.gjin.system.Main$.main(Main.scala:12)
    at ru.gjin.gjin.system.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 36305 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 36305.3 in stage 9.0 (TID 2694, hdp3-sp-024.dmp.vimpelcom.ru, executor 6): java.io.EOFException: host/path/to/file/1612735487120_c186faf5-72c0-4747-884b-58ce29433906.sf not a SequenceFile
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1964)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.initialize(SequenceFile.java:1923)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1872)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileRecordReader.<init>(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.getRecordReader(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1651)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1639)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1872)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1821)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1810)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:194)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: host/path/to/file/1612735487120_c186faf5-72c0-4747-884b-58ce29433906.sf not a SequenceFile
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1964)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.initialize(SequenceFile.java:1923)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1872)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileRecordReader.<init>(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:49)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.getRecordReader(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "empty" SequenceFile will still contain some header info. For example, create a new empty SequenceFile configured to contain LongWritable and check what's inside:

```
SEQ^F!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable^A^@*org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec^@^@^@^@ï<9c>p<84>º74K=æÅ3!<92>^A^F
```

I think that empty SequenceFile (a file which size is 0) is indeed corrupted.

**UPD:**
You can enable malformed file filtering like this:

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf(); 
// ...
conf.set("spark.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", "true")
```

Comment: I have, it is zero. There are no headers. Why doesn't ignoreCorruptFiles work then? And how would I throw empty files away?

Comment: Can you provide a full stacktrace for your error? Here in comments, or on pastebin/gist.github.com

Comment: attached to my post

Comment: For both 3.0.1 and 2.2 the method you encounter looks like this:

```scala
in.readFully(versionBlock); if ((versionBlock[0] != VERSION[0]) || (versionBlock[1] != VERSION[1]) || (versionBlock[2] != VERSION[2])) throw new IOException(this + " not a SequenceFile");
```

And VERSION is "SEQ". 
So if your file doesn't start with SEQ it should fail with EOFException, which should be suppressed later by ignoreCorruptFiles

Comment: @gjin ok I figured it out! Could you please try a different option name: `spark.files.ignoreCorruptFiles`. It should work like this: `val conf = new SparkConf(); conf.set("spark.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", "true")`. And it shouldn't *not* work in SQL syntax like this: `spark.sql("set spark.files.ignoreCorruptFiles=true")`.